# How do I add "Open Folder in cmd.exe" to the shell in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, shell

how do I add an option to open a folder in `cmd.exe` to the context menu of a folder? In Windows XP this can be done by going to the folder options, clicking file types, selecting folder, pressing advanced and creating a new command. Now my question is: How do I do that in Windows 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hold **Shift** while you right click - it's now built in :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd registry key. Then take ownership of the key and after then delete HideBasedOnVelocityId value.